# Occasionally getting 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bad Data' Exception while decrypting string

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I have implemented a class as shown below which is responsible for encrypting/decrypting the text data to a utility class called TextEncryptionData.

It works fine for  %99.99 of the time. But sometime (very rare) it fails to decrypt the text and I don't know why it happens. Is there any problem in the way I implemented it?

```
public class SubscriptionStateEncryptionLogic : IEncryptionLogic
{
    private static byte[] KEY = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 71 };
    private static byte[] IV = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    public EncryptionData Encrypt(EncryptionData source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            TextEncryptionData data = source as TextEncryptionData;
            using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                cryptoProvider.KeySize = 128;
                cryptoProvider.Key = KEY;
                cryptoProvider.IV = IV;
                cryptoProvider.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                cryptoProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                ICryptoTransform transform = cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor();
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
                        {
                            writer.Write(data.Data);
                            writer.Flush();
                            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                            writer.Flush();
                            return new TextEncryptionData() { Data = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length) };
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new SubscriptionStateEncryptionException("Error in encrypting the subscription status.", ex);
        }
    }

    public EncryptionData Decrypt(EncryptionData source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        try
        {
            TextEncryptionData data = source as TextEncryptionData;
            using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                cryptoProvider.KeySize = 128;
                cryptoProvider.Key = KEY;
                cryptoProvider.IV = IV;
                cryptoProvider.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                cryptoProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                ICryptoTransform transform = cryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor();
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(data.Data)))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
                        {
                            return new TextEncryptionData() { Data = reader.ReadToEnd() };
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new SubscriptionStateEncryptionException("Error in decrypting the subscription status.", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the incoming text stream to see if it is valid Base64 when you get the failure?  You could run a quick test with a deliberately invalid input and see what error you get.  Being able to reproduce an intermittent error at will goes a long way towards solving it.

Comment: The input string is passed to this class to decrypt is the output of the Encrypt method of the same class. This utility class is used by one of my services and there is no other process which manipulates this file.